# ExtJS JsonStore and Netty

Tags: java, extjs, netty

Im trying to impelement comunication between ExtJS and Java I'm sending requests from ExtJS to a Java server thats using netty. I would appriciate if someone could send me an example of how the response should be formated from the java side and how to read the response data from the ExtJS side thanks in advance.
This is my source from the ExtJS side

```
var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    autoload: true,
    baseParams: {
        conid : '6b09477f-aa04-4f5a-b969-05277d01f07e'
    },
    root: 'OpenCashTime',
    proxy: new Ext.data.ScriptTagProxy({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/getOpenCash?'
    }),
    fields: [{name: 'Time', mapping: 'Time', type: 'int'}]                  
});
store.load();
store.on('load', function() {
    alert(store.getTotalCount());                   
});
store.on('write', function() {                  
    alert(store.getTotalCount());
});
store.on('loadexception', function() {
    alert("AAAAAA");
});
store.on('metachange', function() {
    //alert(store.getTotalCount());
});
store.on('update', function() {
    //alert(store.getTotalCount());
});
store.on('save', function() {
    //alert(store.getTotalCount());
});
store.on('datachanged', function() {
    //alert(store.getTotalCount());
});
```

When executing this code and reciving this response {"OpenCashTime":[{"Time":1291623637000},{"Time":1294914317000}]} I still get a loadexception although even firebug sees its Json

Comment: Why ScripTagProxy? Will you be loading data from cross-domain source?

Comment: Yes for now I'm testing on localhost plus its not on the same server the ExtJS is running on an Apache Tomcat server and the netty part is running on different port so its counted as cross-domain

Comment: Ok. For ScriptTagProxy, your response must look like this: `callback({"OpenCashTime": [{"Time":1291623637000},{"Time":1294914317000}]})`.

Comment: shouldn't then I add a callback function name?

Comment: Yes. In fact you should configure your ScriptTagProxy with `callbackParam` parameter, which is `The name of the parameter to pass to the server which tells the server the name of the callback function set up by the load call to process the returned data object. Defaults to "callback".` Although I seem to remember, that `callback` is the default value used.

Comment: ok after adding the callback to the json string it doesn't give me a load exception but how do I could this function? sorry for the newbie questions im a bit new to JS

Comment: Please update your code in the question.

Comment: I think I've understood already found a solution +) thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming from your title, that you want to load data into JsonStore, it expects a valid Json string, with a property storing an array of JSON objects, that will be loaded as records. The property name is set up by `root` property when configuring JsonStore.

Store like this:

```
{
  xtype: 'jsonstore',
  root: 'data',
  idProperty: 'ID',
  fields: [
    {name: 'ID', mapping: 'ID', type: 'int'}
    {name: 'someDate', mapping: 'someDate', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'Y-m-d'}
  ],
  url: 'hereBeYourURl'
}
```

Will gladly eat something like this:

```
{"data":[{"ID":"1","someDate":"2002-10-02"},{"ID":"2","someDate":"2002-05-22"}]}
```

Comment: well the string that I get in my response is OpenCashTime{Time:1291623637000,Time:1294914317000} so I guess I should write root: 'OpenCashTime'and in the fields : {name: 'Time', mapping: 'Time', type: 'int'} or should I change somehow the string to fit the currect format?

Comment: For `Ext.JsonStore` you need a valid JSON string. What you have now is far from being a valid JSON. You'd need something like this: `{"OpenCashTime": [{"Time":1291623637000},{"Time":1294914317000}]} `

Comment: although my string is ok now im still reciving an error I'll edit my post and add my ExtJS source code

Comment: @Swine1973: Why are you using a ScriptTagProxy? Are you going to load this data from cross-domain source? If yest, then it needs to be formatted a bit differently. If no, just use default proxy from JsonStore.

Answer (score 1):

```
fields: [{name: 'Time', mapping: 'Time', type: 'int'}]  
fields: [{name: 'Time', type: 'int'}]
```

BTW In the case of an identity mapping you can leave it out. These two cases will give you
the same results.

Comment: Im sorry, but does it help me? If you know that this part of the code is correct?

Comment: I like to have mapping explicitly set. Makes for easier changes.